# start and stop stream consumption in php script from my java frontend

Tags: java, php, mysql, twitter

i am trying to make a project where the user inputs a couple of brands and receives feedback of their mentioned times in twitter.. so far i ve made/found/tweaked the **basic frontend** in java, the **php scripts** for consuming the twitter streaming api plus a **database** to save the incoming tweets,, the **last two in a xaamp server** locally. Its working perfectly but i must run the scripts manually through my browser.

what i need is

1. php scripts to run in the backround (as their creator insists )
2. start and stop scripts at will to change and renew requested keywords

   **and i need this to be done from my frontend**.

i thought of this..

since in the first place i send user inputs to the scripts through my database (java arrayOfBrands => db table => php requests and gets a column as array ) i could do smth like a flag in mysql database changable by my frontend  **and** critical in the execution of my script.

then i looked at this question

[Starting / Stopping php script running in background from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22556777/starting-stopping-php-script-running-in-background-from-browser)

but the guy here proposes to do it as a cronjob... the other guy who made the scripts says about a thousand times in the instructions "DONT DO IT AS A CRONJOB" but as a procedure in the backround... and they both seem good and pro(Adam Green 140dev and Aziz Saleh 1763 fame here ) and i dont know which way to go..

here is "my" code

```
    <?php
/**
* get_tweets.php
* Collect tweets from the Twitter streaming API
* This must be run as a continuous background process
* Latest copy of this code: http://140dev.com/free-twitter-api-source-code-library/
* @author Adam Green <140dev@gmail.com>
* @license GNU Public License
* @version BETA 0.30
*/
ini_set('display_errors', true);
require_once('140dev_config.php');
require_once('brands.php');

require_once('../libraries/phirehose/Phirehose.php');
require_once('../libraries/phirehose/OauthPhirehose.php');
class Consumer extends OauthPhirehose
{
  // A database connection is established at launch and kept open permanently
  public $oDB;
  public function db_connect() {
    require_once('db_lib.php');
    $this->oDB = new db;
  }

  // This function is called automatically by the Phirehose class
  // when a new tweet is received with the JSON data in $status
  public function enqueueStatus($status) {
    $tweet_object = json_decode($status);

        // Ignore tweets without a properly formed tweet id value
    if (!(isset($tweet_object->id_str))) { return;}

    $tweet_id = $tweet_object->id_str;

    // If there's a ", ', :, or ; in object elements, serialize() gets corrupted 
    // You should also use base64_encode() before saving this
    $raw_tweet = base64_encode(serialize($tweet_object));

    $field_values = 'raw_tweet = "' . $raw_tweet . '", ' .
      'tweet_id = ' . $tweet_id;
    $this->oDB->insert('json_cache',$field_values);
  }
}

// Open a persistent connection to the Twitter streaming API
$stream = new Consumer(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET, Phirehose::METHOD_FILTER);

// Establish a MySQL database connection
$stream->db_connect();

// The keywords for tweet collection are entered here as an array
// More keywords can be added as array elements
// For example: array('recipe','food','cook','restaurant','great meal')
$stream->setTrack($mybrands);

// Start collecting tweets
// Automatically call enqueueStatus($status) with each tweet's JSON data
$stream->consume();
```

this is the script i need to run/not run

plz help me in any way possible either code or advice or just a tip are valuable for me.

thanks in advance.

Comment: If I correctly understand your question, then you want: 1. your script running as PHP daemon and get new tweets from twitter stream API. 2. When twitter tags changed by admin you want restart connection and start listening new twitter tags. Right?

Comment: yeah right :) any thoughts about it?

Comment: In this case I suggest save current twitter API config into database. And in your PHP daemon you will check it every 5 minutes. If config was changed you just do reconnect to twitter and work again. I did something like this on `nodejs` and it is working perfectly

Comment: thanks for the tip pal . i will get it working